# How to "repair" a anaconda installation of python2?

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I normally use Python 3 with Anaconda, but I need Python 2 for a project, so I used the following command to create an new environment:

```
conda create -n python2 python=2.7 anaconda
```

It started doing the installation, but when it arrived to `https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/win-64/pyasn1-0.1.9-py27_0.tar.bz2` occurred an "unexpected error", it looks like it is related to a timeout:

```
 conda.exceptions.CondaRuntimeError: Runtime error: RuntimeError: Runtime error: Connection error: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='repo.continuum.io', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /pkgs/free/win-64/pyasn1-0.1.9-py27_0.tar.bz2 (Caused by ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='repo.continuum.io', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=3.05)",)): https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/win-64/pyasn1-0.1.9-py27_0.tar.bz2
```

So, now I have a partial Anaconda installation. It looks like Python 2 works for what I need, but I'd like to repair this installation if possible. I tried to do updates, but it doesn't seem to work.

Any idea, other than uninstall/install?

Comment: What's wrong with uninstall/install? `conda env remove -n python2` and `conda create -n python2 python=2.7 anaconda` should work and be pretty quick.

Comment: Yeah, problem is, since it is timing out, it won't solve anything, it keeps timing out in the same spot, I tried it several times before posting this question. Sorry for not being clear.

Comment: Do you need the entire `anaconda` set of packages? What if you just install what you need?

Comment: Honestly, I suck at managing packages and all that stuff, I use Anaconda because it will load everything. I don't use most of the things, but I suffered a lot installing BeautifulSoup on Windows by myself. It works wonders with Anaconda, so that's why I love it :-)

Comment: IME, `conda install beautifulsoup4` (maybe with `-c conda-forge`) will install on all the platforms Anaconda supports without trouble. Did you have trouble with that on Windows?

Comment: I had lots of trouble (in fact, I wasn't able) installing bs4 when I installed a "standalone" python, but as I said, I really suck at installing environments. When I used anaconda everything went smooth!